# How do I make navigation align left?

Tags: html, css

Trying to make the navigation align left and line break like a normal paragraph. At the moment it seems to break weirdly when hovering.

**Example:**

[image]

Hoping to achieve the below which is only working when I hover on a certain link.

[image]

Code:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {

li {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 8px;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: inline-block.
}


li a:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
}

nav.isotope-filters ul li a:active,
nav.isotope-filters ul li a.selected {
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
}
}
```

I though `inline-block` would resolve this issue but it's not.

Comment: tried display:flex; ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`float` are the guilty. Don't use floats when there aren't nothing to float. And don't mix `float` with `inline-block`. Float transform all displays in block.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {

  li {
    padding-right: 8px;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
  }


  li a:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
  }

  nav.isotope-filters ul li a:active,
  nav.isotope-filters ul li a.selected {
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
  }
}
```